# Returning Multiple Placemarks When Geocoding Address String iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios6-maps

this is my first post on stack. I am new to iOS development, and need help with geocoding.

In particular, according to Apple's documentation: "The number of returned placemark objects depends greatly on the specificity of the information provided. Thus, providing street, city, province, and country information is much more likely to return a single address than just street and city information."

So being broad when providing the address string, should (in theory) return multiple results.

Example:

```
-(void)geocodeAddress {
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"DMV, San Francisco, CA" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Found: %i", [placemarks count]);
        for (CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks) {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
            MapAnnotation *annotation = [MapAnnotation mapAnnotationWithCoordinate:coordinate title:@"DMV" subtitle:@"Great service?"];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error code: %i", [error code]);
    }
}];
```

}

Whats a bit confusing to me, is that regardless of how broad my "search" is (Starbucks, DMV, vs. 1234 S 312th Place, City, State), I ALWAYS get one location returned.

So, my question is, is there a way to return multiple results for s specific search?

Comment: Hi did you ever find an answer to that?  I am getting same thing..

Comment: If someone just needs an example address to pass the CLGeocoder, try passing the string "Springfield", which returns multiple addresses. This is what I used to test as I also had a hard time trying to use street names to get multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CLGeocoder is pretty limited at this stage. Until an update addresses this, your best bet is using another service (e.g. Google Maps Geocoding API). Note that you can only use Google geocoding with a google map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/